# Python-Social-Auth shows 'AuthStateForbidden' sometimes

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

Sometimes when I try to log-in or register with Facebook or Google it returns me an error `AuthStateForbidden` screen

[image: Error screen]
But just refreshing the page or trying again after a while, it run correctly.

I've tried adding `Google+ API` in Google developers but is the same problem with Facebook.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue for several times too. From the documentation we know that:

> AuthStateForbidden      - The state parameter returned by the server
>   is not
>                             the one sent

```
class AuthStateForbidden(AuthException):
    """State parameter is incorrect."""
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Wrong state parameter given.'
```

I have searched for any kind of the solution or workaround with no result. Also I have tried to capture this exception somehow, but it is a tricky error. I don't know how to reproduce it.

I have searched python-social-auth's bug tracker for any presence of `AuthStateForbidden`, as I said - nothing. Moreover, at the moment there more than 50 unsolved issues. Anyways, it is possible to create a [new one](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues).

This error is raised [here](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/b284c76e29d468daeda95297b6845acba01ade4c/social/backends/oauth.py):

```
def validate_state(self):
    """Validate state value. Raises exception on error, returns state
    value if valid."""
    if not self.STATE_PARAMETER and not self.REDIRECT_STATE:
        return None
    state = self.get_session_state()
    request_state = self.get_request_state()
    if not request_state:
        raise AuthMissingParameter(self, 'state')
    elif not state:
        raise AuthStateMissing(self, 'state')
    elif not request_state == state:
        raise AuthStateForbidden(self)
```

Called from [here](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/b284c76e29d468daeda95297b6845acba01ade4c/social/backends/facebook.py) (`facebook.py`):

```
@handle_http_errors
def auth_complete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """Completes loging process, must return user instance"""
    self.process_error(self.data)
    if not self.data.get('code'):
        raise AuthMissingParameter(self, 'code')
    state = self.validate_state()
```

And the state is created in `OAuthAuth`, which implements `BaseAuth` and is a parent of `BaseOAuth`, which is a parent of `FacebookOAuth` and so on... It almost imposible to follow this code.

I hope, that a guthub issue will do the trick in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your time, I also have created an [issue](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues/627) there (but about other topic). I haven't done anything to solve that problem yet, but I haven't saw it again. But I realized that a way to avoid the error screen is write a `SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware` based `middleware` and catch the exception. Anyway, I hope this mistery get resolved soon.